# What is the platform renderer for StackLayout?

Tags: forms, xamarin

I have been grepping through Xamarin's source all morning and can't find out what renderer / VisualElement is responsible for either platform's StackLayout. What is the source that converts a LinearLayout to a platform specific view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, StackLayoutRenderer is what everyone expects Xamarin to do the trick. However, there is no such in Xamarin.

Xamarin handles the native conversion of certain layouts in the `ViewRenderer<TView, TNativeView>` itself. They are mapped to the corresponding NativeViews. As you mentioned there are no explicit files that I could either see to be sure or claim on it. Ever since I started working in Xamarin, am also not sure about this.

However, I believe the StackLayout is internally mapped to either the RelativeLayout or ViewGroup which I could confirm by seeing the below VisualTree. I got this tree when loading an entry and a label inside a StackLayout.

[image: Android Visual Tree]

Maybe, have a look at the `ViewRenderer` and `VisualElementRenderer` class files in each native renderers to have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers#layouts), Android uses `View` and iOS uses `UIView`

Comment: Right, but that doesn't point to what renderer is actually responsible on the platform to create the native view. At some point a StackLayout is converted to a native view. Normally this is done via a renderer. As far as I can tell, the StackLayoutRenderer does not exist.

Comment: "ViewRenderer" - it's right there in that same table

Comment: ViewRenderer is an abstract class. It does not touch nor create native views.

Comment: There may be a subclass to ViewRenderer that does it, but that is what I am failing to find....